# How to generate a readable Allure Report?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, allure, python-behave

Hy, Actually I am trying to generate a readable "Allure Report" but I every time when I run the command Allure Generate or Allure serve. It saves "Allure not found" even though I have installed it using pip. Now I want to generate an HTML format to share with the client, but I am getting nothing.

[ONLY THIS JSON FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxZQS.png)

Allure Generate
Allure Serve

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Allure Commandline tool. Please follow the official docs for the instructions: https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-installation/

Then run

```bash
$ allure generate --single-file path/to/allure-results
```

It will generate a single HTML file, `allure-report/index.html`, that can then be shared with the client.

Comment: Worked, actually I didnt have Java installed so facing that specific issue. Now its working but can you also let me know how to share that report?

Comment: You can share `index.html` via Slack/Email/Google Drive/any other way. The client will be able to open it in any browser by double-clicking on it.